# Links start with two slashes

Tags: html, hyperlink, protocol-relative

More and more, began to notice that the links in the source code on Web sites begin with two slashes. For example:

```
<a href="//example.com/1.png">Image</a>
```

Why do it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's a [protocol-relative URL](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) (typically HTTP or HTTPS). So if I'm on `http://example.org` and I link (or include an image, script, etc.) to `//example.com/1.png`, it goes to `http://example.com/1.png`. If I'm on `https://example.org`, it goes to `https://example.com/1.png`.

This lets you easily avoid mixed content security errors.