# Using tag <c:out in href element

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I hace this piece of code in my JSP:

```
<a href="<c:out value="${item.urlForOnline}"    />"  target="_blank"><c:out value="${item.urlForOnline}"    /></a>
```

The value of ${item.urlForOnline} is www.google.com

But when I click to the link the browser is redirected to http://127.0.0.1:7001/myApp/search/www.google.com

I set the value ot the item object in the spring controller:

```
model.addAttribute("item", item);
```

Comment: Where are you setting the ${item.urlForOnline} value?

Comment: The href is interpreted as a relative URL. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997790/why-does-an-anchor-tags-href-values-need-http-preprended-to-the-url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser is taking `www.google.com` as relative rosource of your site.

You can simply solve this problem by providing the protocol as replacing `www.google.com` with `http://www.google.com`.