# www anchors do not open site

Tags: html

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tmu85p5/)

I have a link in my site:

```
<a href="www.bff.org.uk">BFI</a>
```

This may appear on a page with the URL:

```
mysite.com/articles/60
```

Clicking the link will go to

```
mysite.com/articles/60/www.bff.org.uk
```

I know adding http to the anchor resolves this, but why does www not go to the site? Is there a way to fix it so that www links do go to the site?

Comment: yes, add http:// to the start. or to keep the same protocol add "//", e.g. "//www.bff.org.uk"

Comment: `Basically, any text in the href without a protocol is assumed to be a relative path if there is no / or protocol.` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997790/why-does-an-anchor-tags-href-values-need-http-preprended-to-the-url  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol. Because there are lots of different protocols, so one must be defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...but why does www not go to the site?

Why would "www" imply that the URL's scheme is `http` by default? What if you had a folder named `www.bff.org.uk` set up in your site? Also why couldn't "www" here have a scheme of `https`, `ftp` or `file`? What about `tel`, `app` or even `skype` or `itunes`?

> Is there a way to fix it so that www links do go to the site?

Not without adding in the `http://` part or introducing some peculiar JavaScript to detect and convert this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use http or https protocols

```
<a href="http://www.bff.org.uk/">BFI</a>
```

you should read here
[html - links without http protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951423/html-links-without-http-protocol)