# Appending a link through database with javascript

Tags: javascript

have a script which makes divs in a fore-loop and appends a sentence from a database to it. Now I want to make a link out of the sentence, I do get the styling of a link (blue underlined) but on click nothing happens. 
here is my part of my code:
E D I T E D

```
<html>
<style>
    html,body {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                margin:0;
                font-family: "Nitti Grotesk",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            }
.random {
                position:absolute;
                padding:10px;
                font-size:10pt;
                display:inline-block;
 }


 p{display: inline;}

</style>


<body>
    <div class="allescheissehierrein">
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    //einfach loop mit bis 100 oder was auch immer
    for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
        console.log('test');
    //einen div in eine variable speichern
    //es wird für die datenbank "data-hover" auf den i wert gesetzt welcher ja stetig hochzählt darum alle verschieden
    if (i<24){
        var div = '<div data-hover="'+i+'" class="random">#</div>';
    } else if ((i>23) && (i<47)){
        var div = '<div data-hover="'+i+'" class="random">**</div>';
    } else if ((i>46) && (i<97)){
        var div = '<div data-hover="'+i+'" class="random">-</div>';
    } else if ((i>96) && (i<114)){
        var div = '<div data-hover="'+i+'" class="random">1.</div>';
    } else if (i>113){
        var div = '<div data-hover="'+i+'" class="random">~~</div>';
    }

    //diesen die dem allescheissehierrein-div appendieren (100 mal)
    $('.allescheissehierrein').append(div);
  }

  //diese platzier dings funktionion erst nach der platzierung aller divs (diese 100) machen weil sie ja vorher gar nicht existieren
  platzierRandom();

       //richtig mit jquery UND datenbank
     $('.random').mouseover(function(){
            var hoverdata = $(this).data('hover');
            var satzvondatenbank = datenbank[hoverdata];

        console.log('hoverdata', hoverdata);
        console.log('satzvondatenbank', satzvondatenbank);

            $( this ).append( $( "<span>"+satzvondatenbank+"</span>" ).show('slow'));
     }).mouseout(function(){
        $( this ).find( "span:last" ).remove();
     });
 });


 var datenbank = {
 1: '<a href="www.google.com">So,</a>',
 2: 'so',
 3: 'you',
 4: 'think',
 5: 'you',
 6: 'can',
 8: 'tell',
 9: 'Heaven',
 10: 'from',
 11: 'Hell',
 12: 'blue',
 13: 'Skies',
 14: 'from',
 15: 'Pain',
 16: 'Can,',
 17: 'you',
 18: 'tell',
 19: 'a green',
 20: 'field',
 21: 'from',
 22: 'a',
 23: 'cold',
 24: 'steel',
 25: 'rail?',
 26: 'A',
 27: 'Smile',
 28: 'from',
 29: 'a',
 30: 'veil?',
 31: 'Do',
 32: 'you',
 33: 'think',
 34: 'you',
 35: 'can',
 36: 'tell?',
 37: 'And',
 38: 'did',
 39: 'they',
 40: 'get',
 41: 'you',
 42: 'trade',
 43: 'your',
 44: 'heroes,',
 45: 'for',
 46: 'ghosts?',
 47: 'Hot',
 48: 'ashes',
 49: 'for',
 50: 'trees?',
 51: 'Hot',
 52: 'air',
 53: 'for',
 54: 'a',
 55: 'cool',
 56: 'breeze?',
 57: 'Cold',
 58: 'comfort',
 59: 'for',
 60: 'change?',
 61: 'And',
 62: 'did',
 63: 'you',
 64: 'exchange',
 65: 'A',
 66: 'walk',
 67: 'on',
 68: 'part',
 69: 'in',
 70: 'the',
 71: 'war',
 72: 'for',
 73: 'a',
 74: 'leading',
 75: 'role',
 76: 'in',
 77: 'a',
 78: 'cage?',
 79: 'How',
 80: 'I',
 81: 'wish',
 82: 'how',
 83: 'I',
 84: 'wish',
 85: 'you',
 86: 'were',
 87: 'here',
 88: 'We re ',
 89: 'just',
 90: 'two',
 91: 'lost',
 92: 'souls',
 93: 'swimming',
 94: 'in',
 95: 'a',
 96: 'fish',
 97: 'bowl',
 98: 'Year',
 99: 'after',
 100: 'Year',
 101: 'Running',
 102: 'over',
 103: 'the',
 104: 'same',
 105: 'old',
 106: 'ground',
 107: 'What',
 108: 'have',
 109: 'we',
 110: 'found?',
 111: 'the',
 112: 'same',
 113: 'old',
 114: 'fears',
 115: 'Wish',
 116: 'you',
 117: 'were',
 118: 'here'

 };
  function platzierRandom(){

   w=document.body.offsetWidth;
   h=document.body.offsetHeight;
   rd=document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    for(c=0;c<rd.length;c++) {
      if(rd[c].className=='random') {
         xCoord=Math.floor(Math.random()*w);
         yCoord=Math.floor(Math.random()*h);

      if(xCoord>=w-rd[c].offsetWidth-10){
         xCoord=w-rd[c].offsetWidth-10;
       }
      if(xCoord<=10){
         xCoord=10;
       }

      if(yCoord>=h-rd[c].offsetHeight-10){
         yCoord=h-rd[c].offsetHeight-10;
       }
      if(yCoord<=10){
         yCoord=10;
       }

   rd[c].style.left=xCoord+'px';
   rd[c].style.top=yCoord+'px';
   }
  }
 }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: I dont see a link `<a></a>` created in the code..

Comment: if you scroll down in the code part you see in the database:  `1: '<a href="www.google.com">So,</a>',`

Comment: Can you share more code in order to understand your question... I don't see the method to handle the click event?

Comment: I don t have a click event because I thought if I create a link then it should automatically be clickable, is that not so? I also changed my post and shared the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using events `mouseover()` and `mouseout()` you can use the [jQuery#hover(over, out)](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method that simulates hovering (moving the mouse on, and off, an object). This is a custom method which provides an 'in' to a frequent task.

Parameters description:

- over − The callback function to fire when the mouse is moved over a matched element.
- out − The callback function to fire when the mouse is moved off of a matched element.

Also notice that I have made some code refactor to your code and added `https` to the element `1: '<a href="www.google.com">So,</a>'` of the `datenbank` Object.

See questions and asnwers for: [Why does an anchor tag's href values need http:// preprended to the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997790/why-does-an-anchor-tags-href-values-need-http-preprended-to-the-url)

Code example:

```js
var $allescheissehierrein = $('.allescheissehierrein'),
    datenbank = {1: '<a href="https://www.google.com">So,</a>', 2: 'so', 3: 'you', 4: 'think', 5: 'you', 6: 'can', 7: 'seven', 8: 'tell', 9: 'Heaven', 10: 'from', 11: 'Hell', 12: 'blue', 13: 'Skies', 14: 'from', 15: 'Pain', 16: 'Can,', 17: 'you', 18: 'tell', 19: 'a green', 20: 'field', 21: 'from', 22: 'a', 23: 'cold', 24: 'steel', 25: 'rail?', 26: 'A', 27: 'Smile', 28: 'from', 29: 'a', 30: 'veil?', 31: 'Do', 32: 'you', 33: 'think', 34: 'you', 35: 'can', 36: 'tell?', 37: 'And', 38: 'did', 39: 'they', 40: 'get', 41: 'you', 42: 'trade', 43: 'your', 44: 'heroes,', 45: 'for', 46: 'ghosts?', 47: 'Hot', 48: 'ashes', 49: 'for', 50: 'trees?', 51: 'Hot', 52: 'air', 53: 'for', 54: 'a', 55: 'cool', 56: 'breeze?', 57: 'Cold', 58: 'comfort', 59: 'for', 60: 'change?', 61: 'And', 62: 'did', 63: 'you', 64: 'exchange', 65: 'A', 66: 'walk', 67: 'on', 68: 'part', 69: 'in', 70: 'the', 71: 'war', 72: 'for', 73: 'a', 74: 'leading', 75: 'role', 76: 'in', 77: 'a', 78: 'cage?', 79: 'How', 80: 'I', 81: 'wish', 82: 'how', 83: 'I', 84: 'wish', 85: 'you', 86: 'were', 87: 'here', 88: 'We re ', 89: 'just', 90: 'two', 91: 'lost', 92: 'souls', 93: 'swimming', 94: 'in', 95: 'a', 96: 'fish', 97: 'bowl', 98: 'Year', 99: 'after', 100: 'Year', 101: 'Running', 102: 'over', 103: 'the', 104: 'same', 105: 'old', 106: 'ground', 107: 'What', 108: 'have', 109: 'we', 110: 'found?', 111: 'the', 112: 'same', 113: 'old', 114: 'fears', 115: 'Wish', 116: 'you', 117: 'were', 118: 'here'},
    simbol = '',
    platzierRandom = function () {
      var w = document.body.offsetWidth,
          h = document.body.offsetHeight,
          rd = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

      for (var c = 0, l = rd.length; c < l; c++) {
        if (rd[c].className !== 'random') {
          continue;
        }

        var xCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * w),
            yCoord = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);

        switch (true) {
          case (xCoord >= w - rd[c].offsetWidth - 10):
            xCoord = w - rd[c].offsetWidth - 10;
            break;
          case (xCoord <= 10):
            xCoord = 10;
            break;
          case (yCoord >= h - rd[c].offsetHeight - 10):
            yCoord = h - rd[c].offsetHeight - 10;
            break;
          case (yCoord <= 10):
            yCoord = 10;
            break;
        }

        rd[c].style.left = xCoord + 'px';
        rd[c].style.top = yCoord + 'px';
      }
    };

//einfach loop mit bis 100 oder was auch immer
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

  //einen div in eine variable speichern
  //es wird für die datenbank "data-hover" auf den i wert gesetzt welcher ja stetig hochzählt darum alle verschieden
  switch (true) {
    case (i < 24):
      simbol = '#';
      break;
    case ((i > 23) && (i < 47)):
      simbol = '**';
      break;
    case ((i > 46) && (i < 97)):
      simbol = '-';
      break;
    case ((i > 96) && (i < 114)):
      simbol = '1.';
      break;
    case (i > 113):
      simbol = '~~';
      break;
  }

  //diesen die dem allescheissehierrein-div appendieren (100 mal)
  $allescheissehierrein.append('<div data-hover="' + i + '" class="random"><p>' + simbol + '</p></div>');
}

//diese platzier dings funktionion erst nach der platzierung aller divs (diese 100) machen weil sie ja vorher gar nicht existieren
platzierRandom();

//richtig mit jquery UND datenbank
$('.random')
  .hover(function () {
    var hoverdata = $(this).data('hover'),
        satzvondatenbank = datenbank[hoverdata];
    $(this).append($('<span>' + satzvondatenbank + '</span>').show('slow'));
  }, function () {
    $(this).find('span:last').remove();
  });
```

```css
html,body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  font-family: "Nitti Grotesk",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
.random {
  position:absolute;
  padding:30px;
  font-size:10pt;
  display:inline-block;
}
p {display: inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="allescheissehierrein"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @malina, check that i have added some code refactor that you can improve if appropriate.. Good to help