# How to redirect to the page on another domain with 'a' tag in Vue js project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have an ordinary link to another page in my HTML:

```
<a href='facebook.com'>
```

or

```
<a href='www.facebook.com'>
```

When I click on it, its redirects me to:

my-domen.dev/facebook.com

How to redirect correctly to page on another domain?

Comment: Nothing to do with Vue. You need the `http://`.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thank you sir! If I will work with 'router-link', will solution be the same? I had there the same problem with redirects to anothers domains

Comment: You probably don't want to use `<router-link>` with off-site URLs. Just use a normal A tag for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the protocol if you are attempting to trying to load an external URL.

```html
<p>Right click and open links in a new tab.</p>
<a href="facebook.com">Internal - Will throw 404 - facebook.com</a><br>
<a href="www.facebook.com">Internal - Will throw 404 - www.facebook.com</a><br>
<a href="https://facebook.com">External - https://facebook.com</a><br>
```

You can read more about it here: [Why does an anchor tag's href values need http:// preprended to the URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997790/why-does-an-anchor-tags-href-values-need-http-preprended-to-the-url)