# How to stop html page from jumping when anchor is clicked, but still go to the url in the href?

Tags: javascript

I know that this issue seems similar to many that preceded it, but the main difference is that I still want to go to the url that's in the anchor's `href` and direct them to another page.

Here's my code:
`<a class="tile" href="https://www.weather.com">weather<a/>`

When the anchor is clicked, it jumps to the top of the page right before the user is redirected to the url in the `href`

I've tried adding this to the JS to resolve it, but to no avail.

```
this.el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = this.el.getAttribute('href');
}, false);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need `<a class="tile" href="https://www.weather.com" />` (you were sending the browser to something like `http://yoursite.com/www.weather.com`)

Comment: @ChrisG In the future, sometimes it's best not to remove the jQuery tag on JavaScript questions, even if the question doesn't explicitly mention it; it's an alternative way for OP to signal that they're open to answers that use jQuery.

Comment: @TylerRoper True; I briefly thought about re-adding it before submitting the edit but didn't in the end. It doesn't seem particularly relevant to this question.

Comment: `href=https://www.weather.com` Are you missing the `" "` around `https://www.weather.com`? It should be `href="https://www.weather.com"`. Aside from that, I can't recreate this anywhere; clicking an `<a>` to an external site doesn't jump on the page; it just navigates as expected.

Comment: @TimLewis - I just updated the post, I do supply the quotes.

Comment: I guessed as much, but had to check. Note about being unable to reproduce still stands though... Are you able to provide a live example to demonstrate this?

Comment: @TimLewis - No problem, I appreciate it. The frustrating part is that I can't reproduce it locally, but when another person integrates it into their page, I do see it, but it's not public facing.

Comment: It is invalid to have a self closing anchor tag, for one thing. Where is the anchor text? This is not normal behavior which makes me think something is missing from the information. The context of where that tag is in the page would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need that javascript but simply try adding the http protocol to the front of your url. For example:
`<a class="tile" href="https://www.weather.com" />`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997790/why-does-an-anchor-tags-href-values-need-http-preprended-to-the-url) explains why. Without specifying a protocol, the link will be relative to the current request URI

Comment: Thank you! However, I had a typo. I do have the protocol in the `href`.

Answer (score 0):

It should not Jump. However in your case if it jumps then use dud href and then click event on that:

```
<a class="tile" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick='redirect(event)'>weather<a/>
```

in Script : i think in your example you are missing : window.location.**href**

```
 function redirect(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "https://www.weather.com"; // notice href
 }
```

Comment: I'm able to go to me link in the code I supplied, but it still jumps. I believe the issue is focus related.

Comment: @tim I just edited my post. Main part was missing I think my anchor tag code did not reflect in post. Just edited. Try it out